# Access RBSU on ML350 G6 remotely

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, ilo

We have a remote server having issues and the HP Support guy suggested to

***"Disable No-Execute Memory Protection in the server BIOS."***

This is easy if you have the server onsite and there are many resources on the web how to do this. But how about setting the BIOS remotely? Would that be possible. Trying to search it on the net but found none.

Server: **HP Proliant ML350 G6 ILo 2**

Any help are really appreciated.

Cheers,

Karl

Comment: What issues is the server having? It's rare to need to disable this setting... Especially on the generation of hardware you're speaking of.

Comment: The server experiences random shutdowns and then bsod.

*** Hardware Malfunction ***
_Call your hardware vendor for support
NMI: Channel Check / IOCHK_
*** The system has halted ***

called HP Proliant support team and that's what they suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you mention that you have an ILO 2 on the server. Then that's the solution. It needs to have an IP address that you can access remotely, and even that can be configured from the operating system. The specifics of setting up and provisioning ILO access from the OS depends on the OS itself, and questions about that would be better suited for a different topic altogether.

Nevertheless, ILO gives full KVM access to the pre-OS environment so that you can get into and modify the BIOS settings. You can even mount an image remotely and flash the BIOS or any pre-boot environment that may be residing on a sub-system of the server, including the ILO/BMC itself.

Comment: Do you need a license to do this?

Comment: @Karl You need an ILO Advanced license for the remote graphical console (as well as Terminal Services pass-through). ILO Standard still allows SSH access, and furthermore you can access the RBSU as if it were a serial console, but the catch 22 is that in the BIOS you have to set up the Virtual Serial Port (VSP) to support BIOS serial console options. For more info [see the RBSU manual](http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c00191707-18.pdf) which is quite extensive in its discussion of these topics.